# Adding javascript executor code to string shows error

Tags: selenium

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id(pro.getProperty("")));
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("return arguments[0].text", element);

String cartCountSearchTab = ((String) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("returnarguments[0].text;",driver.findElement(By.id(pro.getProperty(""))))).replaceAll(" ", "");

int cartCountTab = Integer.parseInt(cartCountSearchTab);
```

This above code throws a null pointer exception.

Comment: Which line it's giving null pointer issue

Comment: where have you initialized the driver ?

Comment: null pointer exception shown in 4th line ie. string  declaration.                                how to add webelement to string in case of javascript executor

Comment: @user7309686 This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

There should be space after the keyword **return** in your javascript as given below.

```
String cartCountSearchTab = ((String) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].text;",driver.findElement(By.id(pro.getProperty(""))))).replaceAll(" ", "");
```

Comment: I have already added space in code,it is not showing space above due to some format issue.